# How do I properly reinstall application in the Android emulator from Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I seem to get this error message fairly frequently:

INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

Do I need to do a rest before hitting run or debug from within Eclipse and reloading the application within my emulator?

Comment: No, it replaces the app when you hit run. How big is your app?

Answer (score 2):

I have occasionally received that error despite having plenty of room.  You can first check to see if you are short on space (in the emulator from home screen: Menu -> Settings -> SD card & phone storage).  Internal phone storage is the most important value, and you'll want to uninstall apps if that is low.  If your app is set to install to the SD card, make sure that has enough room too.

If you have plenty of room, sometimes you can just retry the install and it will work.  It can also help to uninstall the app from the emulator and then install it again.  If those solutions don't work, you can restart the emulator.  If all else fails, try creating a new AVD.